# How do I restore the Generator of a GAN from a Tensorflow Model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, generative-adversarial-network

I´m trying to restore the trained Generator of a Generative Adversarial Network using a Tensorflow Model (the metagraph and the checkpoint)

I´m new to tensorflow and python, so I´m not sure if what I´m doing is making sense. have already tried importing the metagraph from the meta file and restoring the variables from checkpoint, but i´m sure what to do next. My goal is to restore the trained Generator from the last checkpoint and then use it to generate new data from noise input.

Here´s a link to a drive containing the model files:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1MaELMC4aOroSQlMJ32J3_ff3wxiBT_Fq?usp=sharing

So far I have tried the following and it seems to be loading the graph:

```py
# import the graph from the file
imported_graph = tf.train.import_meta_graph("../../models/model-9.meta")

# list all the tensors in the graph
for tensor in tf.get_default_graph().get_operations():
    print (tensor.name)

# run the session
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # restore the saved vairable
    imported_graph.restore(sess, "../../models/model-9")
```

However, I´m not sure what to do next. Is it possible to run only the trained generator using this files? How can I acces it?

Answer (score 1):

In the Tensorflow 2 doc, they save **both** the generator and the discriminator. However, they do not explain how to only restore the generator.

```
checkpoint_dir = './training_checkpoints'
checkpoint_prefix = os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, "ckpt")
checkpoint = tf.train.Checkpoint(generator_optimizer=generator_optimizer,
                                 discriminator_optimizer=discriminator_optimizer,
                                 generator=generator,
                                 discriminator=discriminator)
```

And then restore with

```
checkpoint.restore(tf.train.latest_checkpoint(checkpoint_dir))
```

From https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/dcgan#save_checkpoints